# ¿Donde tengo que copiar en el equipo local el instalador de Net Framework para que no me salga mas este error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Para habilitar la opción "Descargar los requisitos previos desde la misma ubicación que mi aplicación" en el cuadro de diálogo Requisitos previos, debe descargar el archivo DotNetFX46\NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ESN.exe para el elemento Microsoft.NET Framework 4.6 (x86 y x64)' al equipo local.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Donde es que te sale este error, que no parece un error si no un aviso?